# How can I define no limit while there is limit clause?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a procedure which gets one parameter as limitation:

```
call proc(2);
```

I use that number `2` in the query like this:

```
. . . LIMIT limitation
```

Noted that `limitation` is procedure parameter variable. Now sometimes I need to set a value which means "no limitation". How can I do that?

I can set a huge number like this: `call proc(1000000000000000)`, but it doesn't seem nice.

---

In PHP configuration, when you set sometime to `-1`, it means no limitation. Now I'm looking for such a thing in MySQL.

Comment: Couldn't you just put a conditional in the procedure for `-1`?

Comment: Leave the `limit` from the query or use a high limit number. Nothing else to do

Comment: @chris85 How exactly you mean?

Comment: @MartinAJ There's an answer below roughly demonstrating it. I was thinking of making a SQL variable and appending it to the query.

Comment: It's nice, even if it doesn't seem so